# Как обратиться к функции из другого класса?

Tags: python, классы, tkinter

```
class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()

    def update(self):
        conn, cursor = BD().connect()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM albums')

        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            self.tree.insert('', tk.END, values=row)

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        self.tree.pack()

class Child(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_child()

    def validation_of_entered_data(self, entry_description, combobox, entry_money):

        BD().add_item(description, combobox, entry_money)
        Main().update()
```

Нужно выполнить функцию обновления из другого класса, я попытался это сделать так

```
Main().update()
```

Но возникла ошибка, я так понимаю, нужно передать какой-то аргумент, но какой - не знаю. Подскажите , что мне нужно сделать, что бы исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас `update` - это не метод класса, а метод экземпляра. Соответственно, нельзя вызвать его просто у класса, сначала нужно создать (или взять уже существующий) экземпляр класса `Main`.

Из описания метода `__init__` класса `Main` очевидно, что для его создания необходимо передать аргумент `root`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Не могли бы вы привести пример кода, я не совсем понял , как мне все это сделать?

Comment: По приведённому вами фрагменту кода нельзя сказать ничего определённого. Скорее всего, где-то за пределами этих классов должен всего один раз вызываться Main(root), а созданный в результате этого объект каким-то образом передаваться в Child. И внутри Child должна идти работа уже с этим существующим объектом, а не вызывать заново Main().

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло!